# Material UI - Styling text inside ListItemText

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to apply style to the text inside a `ListItemText` (Material UI):

```
const text = {
  color: 'red'
}

<ListItem button><ListItemText style={text} primary="MyText" /></ListItem>
```

But the rendered `Typograhy` element inside is not styled at all ("MyText" is not red).

Looking at the generated code, it seems that the default CSS rules for `Typography` > subheading is overriding my CSS.

Thanks for your help

Edit: In the first version of the question, there was a mistake ("className" instead of "style" prop on ListItemText, sorry about that).

Comment: Is ListItemText, a custom defined component

Comment: No, it is a Material-UI component : https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/component-api/list-item-text#listitemtext

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I beleive the only way to achieve this right now is to use the 'disableTypography' prop of the ListItemText element.

```
 <ListItemText
        disableTypography
        primary={<Typography variant="body2" style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>MyTitle</Typography>}
      />
```

This lets you embed your own text element with  whatever styling you want on it.

Comment: The prop type for typography is variant but not type. <Typography variant="body2" style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>MyTitle</Typography>

Comment: Just wasted 10 minutes because I didn't read the above comment. Thanks Hemadri <3

Comment: You could do it like this also, 

```<ListItemText><Typography color={"white"}>Categories</Typography></ListItemText>```

Answer (score 41):

Per the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item-text/#listitemtext-api), the `<ListItemText />` component exposes the prop `primaryTypographyProps`, which we can use to accomplish what you're attempting in your question:

```
const text = {
    color: "red"
};

<ListItem button>
    <ListItemText primaryTypographyProps={{ style: text }} primary="MyText" />
</ListItem>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is the best answer, without having to override the component.

Comment: Can be used like: <ListItemText primary={item} primaryTypographyProps={{style: {fontSize: '30px'}}} />

Answer (score 28):

[this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10294#issuecomment-365716993) is good one, you can implement without disabling typography

```
<ListItemText 
   classes={{ primary: this.props.classes.whiteColor }}
   primary="MyTitle"
/>
```

Answer (score 17):

```
            <ListItem >
                    <Avatar style={{ backgroundColor: "#ff6f00" }}>
                      <LabIcon />
                    </Avatar>
                    <ListItemText 
                     primary={<Typography variant="h6" style={{ color: '#ff6f00' }}>Lab</Typography>}
                     secondary="Experiments" />
                  </ListItem>
```

[image]

Comment: Useful, if you have to pass Dynamic Inline Styles.

Answer (score 11):

**MUI v5 update**

You can leverage [system properties](https://mui.com/components/typography/#system-props) in `Typography` to directly add styling props in the `primary` and `secondary` components inside the `ListItemText`:

```
<ListItemText
  primary="Photos"
  secondary="Jan 9, 2014"
  primaryTypographyProps={{
    fontSize: 22,
    color: 'primary.main',
  }}
  secondaryTypographyProps={{
    fontSize: 15,
    color: 'green',
  }}
/>
```

You can also use `styled` if you want to reuse `ListItemText` in multiple places:

```
import MuiListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const ListItemText = styled(MuiListItemText)({
  '& .MuiListItemText-primary': {
    color: 'orange',
  },
  '& .MuiListItemText-secondary': {
    color: 'gray',
  },
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 9):

Turns out there's an even better way to do this as such:

```
const styles = {
  selected: {
    color: 'green',
    background: 'red',
  },
}

const DashboardNagivationItems = props => (
  <ListItemText
    classes={{ text: props.classes.selected }}
    primary="Scheduled Calls"
  />
)

export default withStyles(styles)(DashboardNagivationItems)
```

You can read more about how this is done here: https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes

Comment: you should write `<ListItemText
    classes={{ primary: props.classes.selected }}
    primary="Scheduled Calls"
  />`. There are root
`inset`
`dense`
`primary`
`secondary`
`textDense` classes to override.

Comment: If `text` was a valid target before, it isn't now.

Answer (score 9):

## Method 1

```
const textColor = {
    color: "red"
};

<ListItemText primaryTypographyProps={{ style: textColor }} primary="BlodyLogic" />
```

For the Secondary Text

```
const secondaryColor = {
   color: 'green'
}

<ListItemText secondaryTypographyProps={{ style: secondaryColor }} 
     secondary="If you say that you" />
```

## Method 2

```
<ListItemText
          primary={
            <Typography variant="caption" display="block" gutterBottom>
              caption text
            </Typography>
          }
 />
```

Custom design:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
      text: {
        color: 'red',
        fontSize: 49
      },
    });
        
/.....// all make classes

<ListItemText
              primary={
                <Typography className={classes.text}>
                  caption text
                </Typography>
              }
     />
```

[Offical Docs](https://material-ui.com/components/typography/)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using material-ui 3.x, this is how it is done:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = {
  listItemText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
}

class YourComponent extends Component {
...
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props; // this is magically provided by withStyles HOC.
    return (
          <ListItem button>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <DashboardIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.listItemText }} primary="My Bookings" />
          </ListItem>
    );
...

}
export default withStyles(styles)(YourComponent);
```

set all your text related styles on `primary` property. Sad that it's hidden so deep in the documentation. https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/

Answer (score 5):

## Material v1.0

I would add something to @SundaramRavi in regards to:

- the way he is using style element which is not great as for Material v1.0 (read the very important difference between [v0.16+](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/styles) and [v1.0](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/).
- the way files can be structured for better separation of concern.

---

<kbd>Whatever.styles.js</kbd>

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  white: {
    color: theme.palette.common.white
  }
});

exports.styles = styles;
```

<kbd>Whatever.js</kbd>

```js
const React = require('react');
const PropTypes = require('prop-types');
const {styles} = require('./Whatever.styles');

class Whatever extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <ListItemText
          disableTypography
          primary={
            <Typography type="body2" style={{body2: classes.white}}>
              MyTitle
            </Typography>
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Whatever.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

exports.Whatever = withStyles(styles, {withTheme: true})(Whatever);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily style text by using `& span`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    listItem: {
        "& span": {
            color: "red"
        }

    }
}));
..
..
..

<ListItem button>
    <ListItemIcon>
        <SendIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText className={classes.listItem} primary="Sent mail"/>
</ListItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your are using **"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4" (4.X.X or newer version)** then it's simple:

**#1st** step: Define your styles like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    // Other Styling if you wish to use it
    root: {
      width: '100%',
      maxWidth: '36ch',
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
    },
    // Other Styling if you wish to use it
    inline: {
      display: 'inline'
    },
    // Styling that you asked for
    textColor: {
        color: 'red'
    }
  }),
);
```

**#2nd** step: **Define** a **constant** to **use** the **specific Styles** like this:

```
const AlignItemsList = (props: any) => {
    const classes = useStyles(); // Like this one
    ......
}
```

**#3rd** step: In your **ListItemText** component do like this:

```
const AlignItemsList = (props: any) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    ......
    <ListItemText
         primary="Your Text Goes Here"
         classes={{ primary: classes.textColor }} // Like this one
         ...
   />
};
```

**#4th** & final step: Just export your component normally without any other stuff, like this:

```
export default AlignItemsList;
```

Answer (score 0):

MUI v5

I recommend to you use global styles for all components. For example you can override styles when you use `createTheme`.

Here is small example:

```
export default createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiListItemText: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    marginTop: 0,
                    marginBottom: 0,
                },
                primary: {
                    fontSize: '1rem',
                },
                secondary: {
                    fontSize: '0.8rem',
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

More details on [official page](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides)